# Android 9.0 systrace for package manager provides empty systrace

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

I tried the following command in my Android which runs 9.0 (Pie) version.

```
python ./systrace.py -o test.html pm
```

but it only provides me with empty systrace in the html output generated, when I generate for all categories, I am able to see other systraces, but not for PackageManager, have also tried to capture the systrace during reeboot, still no systrace for PackageManager, the only time it's present was when I tried to uninstall package from adb.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: Nope, didn't find anything.